# learning motives

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

i'm a beginning graduate student. I would like to learn the theory motives, but i see that the gap is too big. Can someone give me a plan to achieve this goal ? I know a little commutative algebra, differential geometry and some elements of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Just start reading the references given at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306633/what-is-the-best-reference-for-motives). Then you are quickly lead to the prerequisites needed.

Comment: I think the level needed is still too high...

Comment: You should start with a solid couse in algebraic geometry, maybe algebraic topology as well, and learn homological algebra. You can start reading about motives right after that, but you will probably need more advanced topic such as étale cohomology. You can learn these advanced topics when you will encountered them while reading about motives. Also, the theory of motives is quite vast and the word motives is used in a rather large context (pure motives, Voevodsky motives, motivic homotopy, motivic integration...) It would help if you know a bit more what "kind" of motives you want to learn.

Comment: I am not sure if the "project" makes sense, to pick out  "motives" without context. As Roland says, it would make more sense to work up an area like algebraic geometry, homological algebra, algebraic number theory, analytic number theory, commutative algebra, algebraic topology etc.

Comment: I wanted to have a type of plan to achieve this goal. But i know there is a lot of stuff to learn, that's why i was asking for a successful road. Netherteheless i agree, maybe i should learn more on  algebraic geometry, homological algebra, algebraic number theory, analytic number theory, commutative algebra, algebraic topology etc

Comment: Could you explain a little more precisely what you are interested in?

Comment: In fact, i've heard that Grothendieck tried to study the galois group of the rationals with two approachs : one leads to motives, the other to the Grothendieck-Teichmüller theory. My goal was to explore the interwinnings between these two approachs. I don't know much algebraic geometry, but i think it's not difficult to learn this. But in the book of Yves André, there is so many notions that i don't understand that maybe, my question would be : what should i learn for reading this book ?